# Spring boot micrometer statistics - detailed description

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I followed along [this](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2018/05/11/exporting-metrics-to-influxdb-and-prometheus-using-spring-boot-actuator/) article to configure export of my spring boot application statistics to the influx. However, it creates quite a lot of measurements and I can't find any description of what exactly those measurements contain. I would like to have a description of each measurement and what statistics it contains. Anyone could point me where I can find such information?

Regards,

Comment: Where do you expect the descriptions? In the reference manual? Or in the monitoring system?

Comment: I think reference manual should at least mention where is detailed description for collected statistics for various supported monitoring systems. Description itself could be in monitoring system or source code. If its clear where to find it it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the descriptions in the monitoring system itself, some monitoring systems like Datadog support it but looking at the Micrometer source, InfluxDB doesn't seem to be one of them.

If you are looking for them in the reference manual, there's nothing for now. So I created [an issue for it](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/issues/63).

The only way to see them for now is just looking into [the code for meter definitions](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/cache/CacheMeterBinder.java#L51-L58).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm especially interested in http_server_requests measurement. I need mean and maximum request time. Mean is pretty obvious, but I'm not sure about the max. I assume that it might be value called upper however I had rows where upper value was bigger then sum value (Which I assume to be the total time of all requests). I tried to search in the sources, but couldn't find it so far (io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect). Any ideas?

Comment: @MAREK See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsFilter.java#L221-L226 and https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Statistic.java#L39-L42

Comment: @MAREK If you believe the "MAX" doesn't work for you, you'd better open a new question with a sample reproducing it as it does seem to work as expected for me.